# Are there any benefits to food that isn't favoured by anything?

Tags: slime-rancher

For example, Carrots are a type of veggie that is no slime's favourite. Same with Pogofruit and Hen Hens being no one's favourite. Is there a reason to grow/breed these on your ranch, or are they entirely inferior to other food?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there is an advantage to, at the very least, Carrots and Pogofruits. When grown in a garden, food like Cuberries and Mint Mangoes will only produce up to 15 of each in a single harvest, while Carrots and Pogofruits will produce up to 20.
This is particularly useful when feeding Fire Slimes, as any kind of food can be incinerated to produce ash.

While this makes me think a similar mechanic is in effect for Hen Hens, maybe with them breeding or growing up faster than their specialized counterparts, that is harder to test due to the random nature of egglaying.